# xrandr does not change the screen brightnness

Tags: brightness, monitor

I have two screens connected.

```
xrandr --listmonitors

Monitors: 2
 0: +*DVI-I-1-1 1920/598x1080/336+1600+0  DVI-I-1-1
 1: +HDMI-1 1600/621x1200/341+0+0  HDMI-1
```

```
xrandr --current | grep connected

DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 connected 1600x1200+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 621mm x 341mm
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-4-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-3-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-2-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-1-1 connected primary 1920x1080+1600+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 598mm x 336mm
```

However, when I try to change the brightness of the first one, nothing changes visually.

```
xrandr --output DVI-I-1-1 --brightness 0.6 --verbose
crtc 0:    1920x1080  60.00 +1600+0 "DVI-I-1-1"
```

The screen of which I am trying to change the brightness of, is connected with HDMI to USB adapter.
Running Ubuntu 20.04.6 .

Comment: xrandr --current

Comment: @petep added to post